# how can i convert a 9.5 gb mkv file to mpg or avi with avconv?

Tags: 14.04, avconv, video-conversion

I have a 9.5 GB MKV file, and I want to convert it a mpg or avi file using AVConv.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: see ffmpeg (which comes out of the box in Ubuntu 14)

Comment: first install "sudo apt-get install ffmpeg" then show the manual with "man ffmpeg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`avconv -i infile.mkv -c:a copy -c:v copy outfile.avi`

This will not modify the quality.

`avconv -i infile.mkv -c:a ac3 -ab 96k -ac 2 -c:v mpeg4 -s 640x352 -b 800k -bufsize 20M outfile.avi`

This should change size to 'ripped' avi of medium quality (not tested).